# Looping a cut and paste if criteria is met

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am trying to loop the following

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

x = Range("AE4")
y = Range("AD4")

If x >= y Then
Range("AE4").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AD4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Else

End If
```

Once this cell AE4 has been checked and then copied or not depeding of it is greater or = to AD4 i would like this to then move on to AE5, AE6 etc to the end of the data set. any ideas what i need to do next? I currently have the rest of the script executed before this checking iof the a cell date is below 4 weeks and then 5 weeks, 6 weeks old up to 10 weeks. and is currenlty working as expected checking the date of the cell and then checking and copying the first cell in the data.

Full script is as follows.

```
Sub Test()

  Range("AE4").Select
    ActiveCell.Formula = _
      "=IF(RC[-2]>=TODAY()-28,""1"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-28,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-35),""4"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-35,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-42),""5"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-42,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-49),""6"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-49,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-56),""7"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-56,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-63),""8"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-63,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-70),""9"",IF(RC[-2]<TODAY()-70,""10""))))))))"
  Range("AE4").Select
  Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AE4:AE200")
  Range("AE4:AE200").Select

  Dim x As Integer
  Dim y As Integer

  x = Range("AE4")
  y = Range("AD4")

  If x >= y Then
  Range("AE4").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("AD4").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

  Else

  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is some code that'll do what I think you're asking. It looks as though you're relying on the macro generator quite heavily which tends to 'select' a lot more than a developer needs to do. Have a play with your code and look at other posts to see how others do it.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim startCell as Range
    Dim fullRng As Range
    Dim thisCell As Range
    Dim leftCell as Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set startCell = ws.Range("AE4")
    Set fullRng = startCell.Resize(196)

    startCell.Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]>=TODAY()-28,""1"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-28,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-35),""4"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-35,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-42),""5"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-42,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-49),""6"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-49,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-56),""7"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-56,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-63),""8"",IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-63,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-70),""9"",IF(RC[-2]<TODAY()-70,""10""))))))))"
    startCell.AutoFill fullRng

    For Each thisCell In fullRng.Cells
        Set leftCell = thisCell.Offset(, -1)
        Debug.Print("Before If: " & thisCell.Address(False, False) & "=" & thisCell.Value2 & " v. " & leftCell.Address(False, False) & "=" & leftCell.Value2)
        If thisCell.Value2 >= leftCell.Value2 Then
            leftCell.Value2 = cell.Value2
            Debug.Print("After If: " & thisCell.Address(False, False) & "=" & thisCell.Value2 & " v. " & leftCell.Address(False, False) & "=" & leftCell.Value2)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Only issue i have with this is it seems to ignore the 
        If cell.Value >= cell.Offset(, -1).Value Then           
              cell.Offset(, -1).Value = cell.Value
It copies the cell value regardless. if the value is below then i would like this to ignore the copy.

Comment: Hmm. Check the values of each cell just above the if statement. Try Debug.Print (cell.Address(False, False) & "=" & cell.Offset(, -1).Value & " v. " & cell.Offset(, -1).Address(False, False) & "=" & cell.Value).

Comment: I have tried to paste in;          Debug.Print (cell.Address(False, False) & "=" & cell.Offset(, -1).Value & " v. " & cell.Offset(, -1).Address(False, False) & "=" & cell.Value)     Above the if statement and this runs, however the  >= is still being ignored and all cells with a value greter that cell.value are still being overwriten. I also have very little idea what this extra line is doing.

Comment: The Debug.Print line just writes the cell results to the immediate window of your editor (usually at the very bottom) so you can see it - it'll give you the cell address and value contained within it. My suspicion is we're either testing the wrong cells or the values aren't as we think they should be. Just noticed, line should say: Debug.Print (cell.Address(False, False) & "=" & cell.Value & " v. " & cell.Offset(, -1).Address(False, False) & "=" & cell.Offset(, -1).Value). Run it again and see what the values say. If you can't see the immediate window, go to View -> ImmediateWindow.

Comment: The values all look ok.  AE4=5 v. AD4=9.    :  Added the debug after the if statement as well and get the following results.  AE4=5 v. AD4=9  ;
AE4=5 v. AD4=5  ;
AE5=1 v. AD5=9 ;
AE5=1 v. AD5=1  ;

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. You're going to have to step through the code to see what's going on. Place a stop marker on the If line (do this by clicking in the margin next to the line). Run the code and when it stops, click 'Step into' (or it F8) and use the Locals window to see what all the values are. I'm going to edit my post to make this easier for you to see the variables, so use the edited code.

Comment: OK this is now sorted.  Issue was with the multiple "" in the formula not the comparison.  By removing the "" from around the numbers the formula and comparisions now work as expected.  THank you all for your assistance. : startCell.Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]>=TODAY()-28,1,IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-28,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-35),4,IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-35,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-42),5,IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-42,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-49),6,IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-49,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-56),7,IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-56,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-63),8,IF(AND(RC[-2]<TODAY()-63,RC[-2]>=TODAY()-70),9,IF(RC[-2]<TODAY()-70,10))))))))"

Comment: Nice one. Hope that Locals window helped.

Comment: Could you accept one of the answers so that this question is closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably a lopp that just repeats what you are doing.
Instead of defining x and y as ranges, you would only need a count variable:

```
dim lastrow as integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.count, "AE").End(xlUp).row 'counts the amount of cells you have with values in the row

for i = 2 to lastrow 'set 2 = whatever, but I guess you have header rows, if you want to start in the 4th row set it 4

if CELLS(i,31).Value >= CELLS(i,30).Value THEN 'the cell commands uses 1-indexed numbers to refer to cells on an x-y axis, rows go on the x axis so Cells(2,1) is "B1" for some reason.
    'insert your loop here
    Cells(i,31).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Cells(i,30).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
End if
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks Guys these both work , Except for the cell verification. If cell AE4 >= AD4 then copy cell AE4 value to AD4 which worked

Comment: Using `.Select` is "bad" coding practice as there is no real need for it in VBA. instead your code should read: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,30).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,31).Value`

Comment: aware of that; just didn't want to confuse more than neccessary. It doesn't make the thing any slower and for debugging it is actually better in my opinion because it is clearer what the code actually does when you go through it for testing. if you stack some of those loops and then have to debug looking for that one cell index you set wrong it's a massive pain.